# PHP Roomba Serial Port Communication

Tags: php, serial-port, virtual-serial-port

I am trying to communicate with an iRobot Roomba through the serial port using the [PHP class developed by Remy Sanchez](http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?page=2&cid=8658A). I am sure it is sending the data as the iRobot USB cable is receiving the data and lighting up, however, the Roomba doesn't seem to be acknowledging the commands as defined in the [Roomba Serial Command Interface (SCI) Specification manual](http://www.roombadevtools.com/docs_roombasci.pdf). Is there a possible reason for this? Does the class distort the data in some way or does the Roomba require a certain data type to be sent to it that PHP doesn't support?

*Additional Information (I'm not sure if this is relevant)*

Using RealTerm, I can communicate with the Roomba directly using the Send Numbers function (if I try to communicate any other way, it sends every keypress). Using PuTTY, the Roomba doesn't accept my commands, even though I can force local echo + line editing on. It receives the commands, but doesn't do anything with them even though the baud rate is configured correctly.

*Code*

```
require("php_serial.class.php");
$serial = new phpSerial();
$serial->deviceSet("COM1");

$serial->confBaudRate(115200); //Baud rate: 115200
$serial->confParity("none");  //Parity (this is the "N" in "8-N-1")
$serial->confCharacterLength(8); //Character length (this is the "8" in "8-N-1")
$serial->confStopBits(1);  //Stop bits (this is the "1" in "8-N-1")
$serial->confFlowControl("none"); //Device does not support flow control

$serial->deviceOpen();

$start = sprintf("%c",128);
$power = sprintf("%c",133);

$serial->sendMessage("$start");

$time_start = microtime(true);
// Sleep for a while
usleep(1000000);
$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;
echo "Did nothing in $time seconds <br>";

$serial->sendMessage("$power");
$serial->deviceClose();
```

Comment: Wait... Roombas and PHP? Happiest PHP moment ever.

Comment: The code looks perfectly reasonable. Are you logging errors? Do you get any? Is the port name and all the parameters for it the same as what you're using in RealTerm? I'm assuming you're running this PHP code in Windows.

Comment: One thing I just noticed in the SCI docs say the default baud rate is 57600. I'm assuming you've previously changed it in the Roomba to 115200 as you show in your code. You might try some different speeds in your code to see if it's not matched up for some reason. Also, I noticed that the docs [here](http://www.irobot.com/filelibrary/create/Create%20Open%20Interface_v2.pdf) are different than the ones you linked to.

Comment: @Dennis I am not logging errors. I should look up how to do that. The port name and the parameters are the same as in RealTerm. I am running this code on a WampServer in Windows. The SCI docs are for the 4xx series - mine is the 5xx series and therefore the default baud has been upped to 115200 (and a few other commands have changed), but the commands which I reference above have not changed. Using RealTerm / pre-configured programs, I am only able to talk to the Roomba on 115200 baud. The docs you reference are for the Create, not an actual vacuum Roomba. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Dennis Back to my original question, is there a way to determine what RealTerm was sending the numbers as (using the Send Numbers) so that I can mimic that in PHP? Thanks for your help again!

Comment: @tushark: As I said in [my answer](http://superuser.com/questions/245926/how-does-realterm-send-numbers/245929#245929) to your SU question, it's sending byte values. If you type "128" (without the quotes) and click `Send Numbers` it's doing essentially the same thing as `print chr(128)` in PHP.

Comment: @Dennis That's really weird because the Roomba isn't responding to the PHP communication over serial line. Maybe it's something to do with the class that I'm using to communicate with the serial port?

Comment: @tushark: Have you tried using RealTerm's "Spy" mode to spy on your PHP communication to the Roomba?

Comment: No, I will do that the next time I run the code. Is it possible to spy on a port open in another program? Thank you for all the help once again!

Answer (score 1):

The result of -(pow(2, 8) - N) is an integer. PHP internally stores integer values as signed long.

Use [`pack()`](http://docs.php.net/pack)!

Comment: Hi rik,Thanks for the help! How would I use pack() to get it to the same result as a byte (8-bit signed two's complement integer)? Or would it be better to pack it into a different format?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that CR and/or LF is correctly being used after any commands. Some programs automatically send 1, both, or none....

Answer (score 0):

While using Putty your OS is Linux, right? So COM1 might be wrong.
Try something like `$serial->deviceSet("/dev/ttyAMA0");`
And make sure your web-user (www-data?) is within the 'dialout' group.

But first of all get it working from the commandline (Bash):

Correct configuration of the serial port: `sudo stty 115200 -F /dev/ttyAMA0 cs8 cread clocal`

Send some testdata from bash (start passive mode): `sudo echo -n -e "\x80" > /dev/ttyAMA0`

Let the roomba clean: `sudo echo -n -e "\x87" > /dev/ttyAMA0`